# how to simplify the selection query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have to selection queries like below in a stored procedure.

```
SELECT @licenseCount = COUNT(*)  FROM ServicePool SP
INNER JOIN UserPackages UP ON UP.ServicePoolId = SP.Id 
    AND SP.UserId = UP.UserId
INNER JOIN Package P ON P.Id = UP.PackageId
LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyProfile C ON C.LicenseId = SP.Id         
INNER JOIN CompanyProfile CP ON CP.CurrencyId = P.CurrencyId    
INNER JOIN PackageCategory PC ON PC.OrganizationTypeId = CP.OrganisationType 
    AND PC.PackageId = P.Id     
WHERE SP.Active = 1  
    AND SP.UserId = @uId 
    AND P.Active = 1  
    and CP.CompanyID = @cId
    and ISNULL(C.CompanyID,0) = 0 
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),DATEADD(DAY,P.ValidityPeriod,UP.PurchaseDate)) > 0 



SELECT @paymentCount = COUNT(*)  FROM ServicePool SP
INNER JOIN UserPackages UP ON UP.ServicePoolId=SP.Id 
    AND SP.UserId = UP.UserId
INNER JOIN Package P ON P.Id = UP.PackageId
LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyProfile C ON C.LicenseId = SP.Id         
INNER JOIN CompanyProfile CP ON CP.CurrencyId = P.CurrencyId    
INNER JOIN PackageCategory PC ON PC.OrganizationTypeId = CP.OrganisationType 
    AND PC.PackageId = P.Id         
WHERE SP.Active = 1 
    AND SP.UserId = @uId 
    AND P.Active = 1  
    and CP.CompanyID = @cId
    and ISNULL(C.CompanyID,0) = 0 
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),DATEADD(DAY,P.ValidityPeriod,UP.PurchaseDate)) > 0 
    AND UP.PaymentStatus = 'P'
```

As you can see, the only difference between the above two selection queries is that, at the end of second one, there is an extra where condition, `AND UP.PaymentStatus = 'P'`.

So I was wondering is there any way I can simplify this queries?

Comment: what do you mean by "simplify" ? also you will have duplicate data ... why the first one does not have: ```AND UP.PaymentStatus <> 'P'```

Comment: the `UP.PaymentStatus` can be `W or P`, in either case need to take in first condition, and in second take only if `UP.PaymentStatus = P`

Answer (score 1):

Below would be the query

```
SELECT @licenseCount = COUNT(*), @paymentCount = COUNT(case when UP.PaymentStatus = 'P' then 1 else 0 end)   FROM ServicePool SP
    INNER JOIN UserPackages UP ON UP.ServicePoolId = SP.Id 
        AND SP.UserId = UP.UserId
    INNER JOIN Package P ON P.Id = UP.PackageId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyProfile C ON C.LicenseId = SP.Id         
    INNER JOIN CompanyProfile CP ON CP.CurrencyId = P.CurrencyId    
    INNER JOIN PackageCategory PC ON PC.OrganizationTypeId = CP.OrganisationType 
        AND PC.PackageId = P.Id     
    WHERE SP.Active = 1  
        AND SP.UserId = @uId 
        AND P.Active = 1  
        and CP.CompanyID = @cId
        and ISNULL(C.CompanyID,0) = 0 
        AND 
DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),DATEADD(DAY,P.ValidityPeriod,UP.PurchaseDate))
```

You can define @paymentCount variable in the first query itself

Test Results -

```
hive> select * from test_so_t1;
OK
123     90001   90001
123     90001   90002
123     90001   90003
123     90002   90001
123     90002   90002
123     90003   90002
123     90003   90003
Time taken: 0.118 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)
hive> select count(case when mem_id=90001 then 1 else 0 end) as groupBy, group_id from test_so_t1 group by group_id;
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 3 seconds 900 msec
OK
7       123
Time taken: 17.271 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Comment: in your answer `@paymentCount` only return 1 or 0, but i need `count(*)`

Comment: that should not be the case, you will get 1 only if the number of records with Payment_status='P' is either 1 or 0... or issue might be with you query updated my answer with test results as well,